# Upload a file using FTP with SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I need to upload a file using an FTP task in SQL Server 2005 SSIS. While uploading I am unable to get the folders created on the FTP server.

Is there any other solution in SSIS for uploading a file to the FTP server?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean when you say you can't get the folders.

Answer (score 1):

Quite often when I need to use FTP in a DTS or SSIS package, I make a text file with the commands I want executed and then use an "Execute Process" task to run "ftp.exe /s:mycommands.txt".  This can give you a little more control over what happens during the ftp connection.